# Initiate a particular mapping based on the record read

Tags: etl, informatica

I am working on creating a Control Framewrok using Informatica.
I am maintaining a list of all the files to be loaded in a relational table.
For a particular type of file, I wish to initiate a different mapping.
How should i go about doing this.

Help/ Pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use router transformation.

Took some time to figure this one out.

Thanks anyway. Hope this helps someone else. :)